# Clearcase trigger on checkin and mkelem

Tags: clearcase

In our VOB we have a ClearCase trigger that doesn't allow `checkin` and `mkelem` actions without comments, but `checkout` comments are optional. Our SCM guys are OK with not having checkout comments, but want to enforce checkin comments.

The issue is that `mkelem` usually doesn't do checkins, so I'd expect a `ct mkelem foo` to be allowed, since this would only create version `/main/0` and check it out. Only when doing `ct mkeleme -c "some_comment" -ci foo` would a checkin happen and the comment would be used for the newly created version `/main/1`.

Is it possible to implement a trigger so that it checks if an `mkelem` was started with `-ci`? This would be more homogeneous and would fulfill the policy that only checkin comments are mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the "Trigger Environment Variables" section of [`cleartool mktrtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm), you should be able to query the value of the EV (Environment Variable) `CLEARCASE_COMMENT`.

That way, you know if your command was launched with `-c` or not, and is probably used for your current pre-op checkin trigger.

But for [`mkelem`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_elem.htm), there is no clear indicator of a `-ci`, except that it will trigger a checkin.
So maybe it is easier to rely on your existing pre-op checkin: if the `mkelem` does not use `-ci`, the lack of comment does not matter. And it is uses `-ci`, the lack of comment will be caught by the pre-op checkin trigger.

Comment: The SCM responsible wasn't really sure if it's supposed to work like this (i.e. if a `checkin` from `mkelem` is supposed to register as a normal `checkin`). It would have also seemed silly to me if it weren't like this, since it makes more sense to trigger on events, not on the commands themselves. This wasn't really clear from the documentation (at least not on the glance I threw at it). Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Checkin from mkelem looks exactly like a normal checkin, which is sometimes annoying.

Unless you did the mkelem -ci from the "cleartool" command line, in which case CLEARCASE_CMDLINE will be set to say "mkelem ...", the mkelem operation will fire the checkin trigger in exactly the same way that a "normal" checkin will.

You may want to change your "-preop checkin" trigger to be "-preop checkin,mkelem" since the mkelem comments are the checkin comments for the checkin at the end of a mkelem -ci.